# How to improve the quality of the audio of RTMP stream after multiplexing two streams

Tags: python, ubuntu, audio-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

Using **GStreamer** (gst-launch1.0), I am multiplexing two streams

- One contains the silence
- Other contains the audio speech

But the problem is that the quality of the audio output is not good. The voice is distorted.

I need your help to improve the quality of the audio and here is my gstreamer command with parameters:

- Below is the command which I used to multiplex two streams:

  ```
  gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc name='src1' caps="application/x-rtp" port= ! 
  rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! mix. udpsrc 
  name='src2' caps="application/x-rtp" port= ! rtppcmudepay ! mulawdec ! 
  audioconvert ! audioresample ! mix. audiomixer name=mix start-time-selection=1 
  ! audioresample ! alawenc ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp:server_ip
  ```
- Below is the plugin which I used to improve the quality of the audio:

  ```
  audiochebband mode=band-pass lower-frequency= upper-frequency= type=2 ! 
  audioamplify amplification=0.5 clipping-method=wrap-positive
  ```

But this plugin is also not working to improve the quality of the audio stream.

I would really appreciate if you help me out to get the good quality audio output after multiplexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to improve the quality of the audio by changing two parameters in the command rtppcmudepay with rtppcmadepay and mulawdec with alawdec Thanks

Comment: Mark this as accepted answer, if this worked for you.